# How should I search for entries in A2:A where the B2:B cell on the same row equals F2?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m not as experienced at queries as I’d need to be to figure this out on my own. The best I’ve come up with is

=QUERY({A2:A,B2:B,F2},"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col2 is not null group by Col3")

but that doesn’t work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"select A where B='" & F2 & "'",0)
```

Comment: Thank you! If you have time, could you please explain how this works?

Comment: @FishInaTree0 Can you please post few sample data or share a sample workbook.